# Replace JavaScript code of HTML files with Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, replace

I am trying to insert a piece of JavaScript before the closing `<\body>` tag of over 2000 HTML files. This is what I have tried. But it does not do the job.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\<\/body\>/\<div id=\"fb-root\"\>\<\/div\>
    \<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"https:\/\/connect.facebook.net\/en_US\/all.js\"\>\<\/script\> 
    \<script type=\"text\/javascript\"\>

    FB.init\(\{
        appId: \"446059218762070\", 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });

    \/\* As of Jan 2012 you need to use \*\/
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow\(2\);
    \<\/script\>
\<\/body\>/g' *.html
```

I have done some other replacement scripts with `perl -pi`, that worked well like

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\<a href=\"index.html\"\>/\<a class=\"top_button\" href=\"index.html\"\>/g' *.html
```

and

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\<link rel=\"STYLESHEET\" type=\"text\/css\" href=\"default.css\"\>/\<link rel=\"STYLESHEET\" type=\"text\/css\" href=\"default.css\"\>
\<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.4\/jquery.min.js\"\>\<\/script\>
\<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"default.js\"\>\<\/script\>/g' *.html
```

Can anyone help me? what is wrong with my one-liner Perl script?

Comment: have you tried counting the matches of the regex? It could be a letter is off or something

Comment: Well I copied the exact HTML/JavaScript in to the script from one of the HTML files. That should be correct right?

Comment: @WebsiteMount: Removing the `<script>` elements won't work in the same way as adding them. Your one-liner reads the file one line at a time and searches for a multi-line string in each one, so it will never be found. Surely there is a backup of the files you modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to do a multi-line search and replace but are processing the files line by line. The following modified one-liner should work:

```
perl -i -wpe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s[<div id="fb-root".+?</body>][</body>]gs' *.html
```

Note that I have simplified your search string. It's not necessary to repeat the whole HTML/JavaScript sequence character by character. There were also several meta-characters that should have been escaped in the search string.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why it would fail, but you are unnecessarily escaping far too many characters so that any mistakes become invisible.

You aren't using square brackets in the pattern or the replacement string, so I suggest you use them to delimit the substitution, like this

```
perl -i -wpe 's[</body>][<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

    FB.init({
        appId: "446059218762070", 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });

    /* As of Jan 2012 you need to use */
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(2);
    </script>
</body>]g' *.html
```

Just one shot in the dark: I wonder if the `</body>` tag in your files is in upper case? In that case your match would fail. I suggest you add the `i` modifier (making `gi`) just to make sure.

Comment: I just tried it and for some strange reason it says  "No such file or directory". Then I saw only now that I gave you the wrong order. You see I first added this JavaScript line and it worked so the line I gave worked, but then I wanted to remove it again. And changing places that instead of adding the lines I now want to remove them, it does not work.. I will edit my post to show the script I just used and it still did not work.

Comment: I got the script to run with out giving the error "no such file or directory" by using `-pi -w -e ` instead of `-wpie` but it still does not replace the HTML/JavaScript